# PostgreSQL: Is there a way to insert my data piece by piece in the empty table to reduce the loading time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, time, sql-insert

I have a very simple query as follows.

```
drop table if exists table1;
create table table1
  select
    account,
    campaign_id,
    customer_id,
    type,
    min(date) as date_min
  from table2
  where account in ('1','2') and campaign_id not in ('1','2','3')
  group by account, campaign_id,customer_id,type;
```

However, every time I run this, I get this error message saying that "java.io.IOException: the connection is closed by remote host". I believe it is because the data is too big.

Someone suggested me to loop 'insert into' statements and add the data pieace by piece in the empty table.

So I tried to add the data year by year. The below code is just for 1 year. I need to insert into multiple times.

```
insert into loop_dk (account, campaign_id, customer_id, type, date_min)
select account,
       campaign_id,
       customer_id,
       type,
       min(date) as date_min
from dk
where account in ('1', '2')
  and campaign_id not in ('1', '2', '3') and date between '2016-11-29' and '2017-11-29'
group by account, campaign_id, customer_id, type;
```

Can anyone tell me if it is good to loop 'insert into' statements or suggest me any other solutions that can prevent the above error message?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: "*the connection is closed by remote host*" could indicate that your statement timeout is simply too low. you can use e.g. `Statement.setQueryTimeout(0)` to disable that. Or maybe there is a limit defined on the server, then try `set statement_timeout=0`

Comment: Look in the PostgreSQL server's log file to see why it closed the connection.

Comment: Why are you even repeatedly running a query like that? It seems like what you actually need is a materialised view.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions! I will work on them.

Comment: @Bergi we are using Amazon Redshift, and unfortunately, it doesn't support materialized views.